# Invisible columns in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to alter the name of a column in a view/table. This column is used by a lot of users in the organization so i wanted to make the change in a way that doesn't break everyone's scripts. While i want to discourage the use of the old column name, i do not want to break all other scripts that use the old name instantly.

I understand i can just copy the column for now but that would duplicate the data and may confuse people.

Is it possible to implement an [invisible column](http://www.juliandyke.com/Research/Database/InvisibleColumns.php), or a make a column referable with an alias that isn't visible in the table/view?

Note i have the ability to re-create the table.

Comment: Teradata has no concept of "invisible" columns. And if you can use the view (or table) then you can retrieve the metadata (with all columns listed).

Comment: If users follow the recommended approach and access the table via a view level, you might simply add the column twice (old & new name) to the view.